# Probability based on dices

Tags: probability

There are three unbiased dice of different colours. These three dice are rolled simultaneously.Then probability that sum of numbers on any two of them is equal to the number on third die.

Can anyone please tell me how to tackle this problem

Thanks.

Comment: Are all three of the dice same-sided? And how many sides to each dice?

Comment: Is the information that they have different colours relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just list all possible combinations: 1,1,2; 1,2,3;  etc. (there really aren't too many combinations that work so you can exhaust them pretty quickly) and note that 1,1,2 (two the same and 1 different) can occur in three different ways, and something like 1,2,3 (where they are all different) in 6 different ways.  Add up all those ways and divide by $6^3=216$  (I am assuming you are talking about 6-sided dice...)

Answer (score 1):

It's the number of valid ordered pairs times $3$, there being $1$ for $n=2$, $2$ for $n=3, \dots, 5$ for $n=6$, total $15$. Multiply by $3$, divide by $216$.

$$\frac{45}{216}=\frac{5}{24}$$.